# Do dynamic URLs have their own PageRank?

Tags: url, pagerank

Do URLs with parameters have their own PageRank for the given parameters values or is the PageRank aggregated at basic page URL level ignoring the parameters?

Comment: Also worth mentioning that PageRank hasn't been updated in over almost 8months so pretty useless to say the least. Expect many NA's.

Comment: @bybe Google is still calculating PageRank internally, just not updating the public figures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each page (= each URL with parameters or not) Google finds, Google assignes PageRank. Remember Googlebot goes from URLs to URLs.